# How i write inline conditional statement in Flex with two expressions(case)?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml

How i write the  inline conditional statement in Flex with two expressions(case)

like

```
text="{expression, expression2 ? true:false}"
```

Flex compiler only check the first expression and on behalf of that give result.But i want to check both statement and show result. if no condition met then do nothing.

Comment: Probably something like `text = ((expression) && (expression2)) ? true : false;` or  `text = ((expression) || (expression2)) ? true : false;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them in one `if` statement, use the `and` or `or` operators: `&&~ and`||`, respectively. For example:

```
var x:int = 6
if (x > 3 && x < 10) {
    trace("both are true, so its contents will be acted on.");
}

var bob:Boolean = true;
if (x > 10 || bob) {
    trace("x > 10 is false, but bob is true, so this will also be acted on.");
}
```

You can also use functions that return booleans

```
function y (z:int):Boolean {
    if (z < 10) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Actually, I could simplify that to

```
function y (z:int) {
    return z >= 10;
}
```

Then use the function in a group of conditions:

```
if (x < 5 && y(x)) { trace ("something here"); }
```

Booleans are converted to strings if assigned to or concatenated with a String.

Comment: Please Note that i want to write in MXML not in action script 3.

Answer (score 11):

If I understand your question correctly either:

`text = ((expression) && (expression2)) ? true : false;`

or `text = ((expression) || (expression2)) ? true : false;`

**[UPDATE 1]**

Well I say either, but the first tests to see if both conditions are true, where as the second tests if either condition is true which I believe is the one you want.

**[UPDATE 2]**

An example

`((1.1 is int) && (1.1 is Number)) ? true : false;`

This will give you false as the expression `(1.1 is int)` is false, and both expressions must be true to return true.

`((1.1 is int) || (1.1 is Number)) ? true : false;`

This will return true as the expression `(1.1 is Number)` is true, and only one expression has to be true to return true.

**[FINAL UPDATE]**

Last example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:VGroup>
        <s:Label id="label1" text="{((1.1 is int) &amp;&amp; (1.1 is Number)) ? 'true' : 'false'}"></s:Label>
        <s:Label id="label2" text="{((1.1 is int) || (1.1 is Number)) ? 'true' : 'false'}"></s:Label>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Because you get an error if you use `&&` alternatively you can use `&amp;&amp;`.

Comment: @wvxw I'm not sure what you mean, if you were the one that downvoted my answer, can you explain to me how my answer was wrong. My answer might be wrong but I don't understand what your trying to say in your comment in relation to my answer be wrong.

Comment: in simple word i have data in three condition

Comment: 1st - true, 2nd - false and 3rd is not true not false so i point out that if i only implement two condition in my question expression and expression 2. Mean if expression is matched then text populate according to that and if expression 2 is matched text populate according to that but for now it only check the 1st condition and on behalf of that populate result.

Comment: @wvxw its still not clear to me at all what you mean, 2 other people answered more or less the same as me increasing the odds that my answer is correct. Also my comment to this question (at the top of the page, which is more or less the same as my answer) as well as my answer were both voted up, therefore (to me) further affirms that my answer is correct(since other seem to agree). Don't get me wrong, it's not like I'm saying that my answer is wrong, just that I do not understand how exactly it is wrong. Can you please explain clearly?

Comment: @Tahir Alvi I thought your question was pretty clear but apparently it's not, can you please update your question with the current code your using, that way I can try and deduce what exactly your problem is via your code.

Comment: oh, ok, I'm pretty sure your talking about something that has nothing to do with my answer, therefore your downvote wasn't justified, thats all I wanted to know.

Answer (score 5):

There are number of methods, you can just write like that :

`(condition1 && condition2) ? statement if true : statement if false`

but if you want to execute this code in mxml component bindings, then you must use :

`'&amp &amp'` instead of `&&`,`'&lt'` instead of `<`, etc.

Comment: yeah that good but can you provide me an example with code in mxml?

Comment: @TahirAlvi here is the code, suppose you have a button and you want to set its enable property true when its first name and last name containing text. <mx:Button id='btnShow' enabled='{txtFirstName.text!='' &amp;&amp; txtLastName.text!=''?true:false}'/>

Comment: @TahirAlvi if you have any problem feel free to ask, i insha Allah definitely try my best. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would write the following statements instead :

```
var expression1:Boolean;
var expression2:Boolean;
var result:Boolean;

expression1 = condition?true:false;
expression2 = anotherCondition?true:false;

result = expression1&&expression2;
```

Comment: i want solution in mxml not in Action script 3